# How do I promote my idea using a video without the risk of it being copied?

Tags: intellectual-property

I plan to create a video to promote my idea for an app. Quite similar to how Google's Pokemon Challenge Video turned into Pokemon Go. I would like people to see how my app would look like and how it can be used when it is finished. I guess I am a little paranoid on people actually copying my idea. Do I have to get a copyright for my idea or can I do something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideas are [not subject to copyright protection](http://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ31.pdf). See [17 USC 102](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/102):

> In no case does copyright protection for an original work of
>   authorship extend to any idea, procedure, process, system, method of
>   operation, concept, principle, or discovery, regardless of the form in
>   which it is described,  explained, illustrated, or embodied in such
>   work

If you want protection, keep your ideas to yourself and create a concrete expression in the form of a program, which *is* protected by copyright.

Comment: Just to clarify if you make a youtube video of your idea you are not protected but if you write a book, get a paper published in a journal, or create a physical prototype it would be protected?

Comment: No, the idea is not protected, the video (expression) is. Expression is protected, ideas are not.